# Different Drupal front page from different country

Tags: php, drupal, redirect, geoip

I have a drupal site, and i want to redirecting visitors to a different page based on the country.
I have this code:

```
require_once "Net/GeoIP.php";
$geoip = Net_GeoIP::getInstance("Net/GeoIP.dat");
try {
    $geocode = $geoip->lookupCountryCode($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $geocode = 'EN';
}
switch ($geocode) {
    case 'HU':
        header('Location: http://www.example.com/hu');
        break;
    case 'GB':
        header('Location: http://www.example.com/en');
        break;
    case 'AT':
        header('Location: http://www.example.com/at');
        break;
    case 'CY':
        header('Location: http://www.example.com/cy');
        break;
    case 'DE':
        header('Location: http://www.example.com/de');
        break;
    case 'NL':
        header('Location: http://www.example.com/nl');
        break;
    case 'CH':
        header('Location: http://www.example.com/ch');
        break;
    case 'ES':
        header('Location: http://www.example.com/es');
        break;
    case 'US':
        header('Location: http://www.example.com/us');
        break;
    default:
        header('Location: http://www.example.com/en');
}
```

This works well on plain php file. How can i this in drupal?
How can i redirect the visitors to the proper node?

Comment: just something to thing about: 1 year ago i was in korea, and since then i know there is nothing more annoying then redirect to a specific locale by ip (no i cant read korean, so stop redirecting me! just give me the choice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand neither why not using an existing solution but still: have you tried putting your snippet inside page.tpl.php? Just make sure the path to the required library is correct. You might wanna put Net/GeoIP.php inside your sites/all/libraries folder and thus change **require_once "Net/GeoIP.php"** to **require_once "../../libraries/Net/GeoIP.php"**. This is assuming that your page.tpl.php is located inside **sites/all/themes/*yourtheme*/**

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use http://drupal.org/project/ip2locale

It supports GeoIP.

Comment: Sorry No, I can redirect users without any module. I want to apply my code. This code works, but I've never used in drupal page.

Comment: Why do you want to apply your own code? The whole purpose of Drupal is to use pre-existing modules so you don't need to re-invent the wheel. The module I suggested will achieve the _same_ thing you want. Why don't you try out and see if it fits your needs? If it doesn't fit your needs then you can try using your custom code.